# Use variable in batch file multiple times

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm trying to compile a batch file to get the userID of the current user, then use the output to delete a certain registry key.

I found this to get the SID of the current logged in user:

> wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid

This worked perfectly and gave me:

> SID
>
> S-1-5-21-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXX

Now I would like to use the S-1-5-21.... etc. To delete a certain registry key for the current logged in user, so the S-1-5-21 etc. How can I do that? Or is there an easier way, being able to determine current SID and delete a key consequently?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete the registry key...

```
HKEY_USERS\[SID-OF-USER]\test
```

...this script should cut it:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET USERNAME=SomeUserName

:: retrieve user's SID, store in file. NOTE: a user can have more than 1 SID.
wmic useraccount where name='%USERNAME%' get sid | FINDSTR "^S-" > tmp.txt

:: load result into variable. NOTE: this will load the first line only.
SET /P SID_=<tmp.txt

:: remove spaces which turned out to be appended at the end.
SET SID=%SID_: =%

:: delete key in the registry (will probably required elevated privileges)
:: the /F causes reg.exe not to ask for confirmation
REG DELETE "HKEY_USERS\%SID%\test" /F

:: cleanup
DEL tmp.txt
```

I'm not aware of an easier way to "determine current SID and delete a key".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I made a small variation on this and it worked perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get sid > temp.txt &more temp.txt > temp2.txt &del temp.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (temp2.txt) do set "userID=%%A"
del temp2.txt
echo %userID%
pause
```

You can use the %userID% variable after this code.

Note that you need to use the more because of the way wmic parses it's output